# .xlsm files freezes over activating after long hrs of inactivity

Tags: excel, vba

Like suppose, your .xlsm file is about more than 5 mb

It has more than 20 sub procedures any many more. Many inbuilt formulas & functions are used in the background on the excel sheet. Yes, more than 20 Excel sheets. So this is how large Excel VBA Application looks like.

Now, I found one issue with the large application, It stops working or freezes or not respond when your application is open in your system for more than few hrs without having any action on it!

Yes, and as soon as you activate your workbook after a long hr of other work, workbook almost freezes or showing not responding. and we need to close the excel file anyhow for further any process.

It's very common encounters who has worked on large excel files. Please discuss here the reasons, causes, and solutions.

Comment: `Autosave`, I suspect. Disable it if is really causing significant issues that outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Yes it does matter but I think reason is still different. May be with Windows or something. Because it happens with browser also. Leave 5 minit open and inactive you browser with some website, when you get back to it.. it perform the same kind of freezing.

Comment: Probably not a question for an Excel-vba forum then. Maybe check what the PC is doing, using Task Manager and/or discuss with your network / I.T. people. Best of luck!

Comment: @CLR No buddy, it's definitely a question for an Excel VBA forum only because I required solution for excel and may have excel bas some features which will have facility which makes these things settle down  and only excel VBA users can know..?! So I'm in a right place.

Comment: You've just said yourself *May be with Windows or something*.. From personal experience using **Excel** for the last 20 years or so, the most common reason for lockups *matching your description* is Autosave kicking in - sometimes combined/conflicting with other vba Events. You're asking too broad a question for this forum if you're talking about outside Excel. **This is a forum where posters put forward their code and ask for help getting it to work the way they intend**, not really a discussion board for the finer points of using large files across a network.